# Cross language and server http session variables

Tags: java, php, http, jetty, session-variables

I have one problem of retrieving http session variables. I have two sever, one jetty and one apache. And two languages PHP in Apache and Java in jetty. When the user login to the website, his or hers profile ID is stored as Session variable in the Apache server in PHP. Can I somehow retrieve this session variable from the Jetty server using Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cross server session you can keep session in cookies. But you need to make sure that these cookies are encrypted using some strong algorithm and key.

If you want to store only user ID. Then you can store ID as it is if its public ID and store a signature along with that, if ID is tempered with you can detect it using signature.

Create two cookies after authentication

```
  1. One contains ID and 
  2. other contains signature of ID like using function in php called hmac_hash
```

[hmac_hash](http://in.php.net/hash_hmac)

Whenever you get a request which needs authentication.

```
  1. Using ID and same secret generate same signature back.
  2. Check if the signature you generated is same as one you got in cookie.
```

**Warning**: Slight mistake can make data public.
**Warning 2**: Large cookie will make site a bit slower.

Comment: I'm not good in security, but how is a strong encryption along with cookies going to help enhance my user's security? Isn't it the same as storing ordinary cookies?

Comment: In session if you store some data which should not be public like may be his name or email. In that case if data is encrypted then whoever copies the cookie wont be able get decrypt it and know what is the actual data. Since you have secret key to decrypt it you can read the data.

Comment: @Zimbabao: Can you tell me how to do it in PHP?

Comment: Is your requirement of sharing only ID or you want to share lots of other data.

Comment: I made changes to the answer.

Comment: I have a follow up question. Can cookies be retrieved with AJAX or is it just new pages? And cant they copy both cookies to retrieve information?

Comment: Yes. You will get cookies with AJAX. What is the host names of your both the servers. They are under same main domain ?

Comment: Who?. Some exploiter ?, he can copy but will get only ID and signature it to make sure that somebody doesn't change the ID and access someone else's data.

Comment: yes but a hacker who copies someoneelses pair of cookies can retrieve the info about the user right?

Comment: Ok think I got the answer in wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

were it me, i'd be tempted to override the session handlers in php and store the session stuff in a database. see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

that way you control how the session variables are stored and where they are stored. you can read the session handle from the cookie or whatever in either language and write your own stuff for the java side.

Comment: Yes but there's a huge performance hit when shifting from native sessions to DB persisted sessions.

Comment: Use the memcached session handler instead. It works brilliantly.